# Compare all documents to other documents in Perl's Text::DocumentCollection

Tags: perl

Given a document collection in [`Text::DocumentCollection`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::DocumentCollection) in Perl, I want to calculate the [cosine similarity](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::Document) between any two documents in the collection using [`Text::Document`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::Document).

I think this can probably be done using `EnumerateV` and callbacks, but I'm having trouble figuring out the specifics. ([This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389605/how-can-i-use-callbacks-with-perls-textdocument) is helpful, but I'm still stuck.)

To be specific, suppose the collection is stored in `test.db` as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Text::DocumentCollection;
use Text::Document;

$c = Text::DocumentCollection->new( file => 'test.db' );

my $text = 'Stack Overflow is a programming | Q & A site that’s free. Free to ask | questions, free to answer questions|, free to read, free to index';

my @strings = split /\|/, $text;
my $i=0;

foreach (@strings) {
    my $doc = Text::Document->new();
    $doc->AddContent($_);
    $c->Add(++$i,$doc);
}
```

Now suppose I need to read in `test.db` and calculate cosine similarity for all combinations of documents. (I don't have access to the documents created in the code above other than through the stored database file.)

I think the answer is in constructing a subroutine that is accessed with the callback in `EnumerateV`, and I'm guessing that the subroutine also calls `EnumerateV` but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to start with something like this:

```
$c->EnumerateV(sub {
    my ($c, $k1, $d1) = @_;
    $c->EnumerateV(sub {
        my ($c, $k2, $d2) = @_;
    return if exists $dist{$k1.$k2};
    $dist{$k1.$k2} = $dist{$k2.$k1}= cosine_dist($d1, $d2);
    });
});
```